# Disable the screenlock on Samsung Galaxy Tab with forgotten password?

Tags: lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-tab, password

I was given a Samsung Galaxy Tab last year for my birthday and I put a password on it but now when I try to get back into it I can't as I have forgotten the password.

I was just wondering if there is a way to disable the screenlock without deleting the files on the tablet.

Answer (score 2):

Try Hard Reset.
To Hard Reset please follow the below steps.

1. With the device off, press and hold **Volume Up**, **Power** and **Home** button.
2. Release the **Power** button when you see the **Samsung logo**, but continue to hold **Volume Up** until the recovery screen appears.
3. Use the **Volume** buttons to navigate the menu and select **wipe data / factory reset**. Press **Power** to choose the selection.
4. Press **Volume Up** continue.

*Note: These steps clear data from the device. SD card data like your photos and music are not erased unless you choose to format the SD card. You may have to lose some files, but some of them may be able to be recovered.*

Comment: The question states "I was just wondering if there is a way to diable the screenlock *without deleting the files on the tablet.*"

Comment: try multi tools http://forum.gsmhosting.com/vbb/f606/utility-android-multi-tools_1-0-reset-user-lock-gmail-wipe-data-azimbahar-1620378/

Comment: The link you posted leads to a method that works on FastBoot. Samsung devices (excluding the Galaxy Nexus) don't have FastBoot.

Comment: 1 - 6 command do not require fastboot mode.

Comment: I guess you're right, I must have overlooked it. (I need sleep.)

Comment: Can't shut it off without entering the pin in my case...

Answer (score 1):

If you had its bootloader unlocked before, the following steps are simple to follow.
1. (Skip if done) Flash a custom recovery
2. Reboot into that custom recovery, connect the Tab to a PC (with adb installed on it), open a command prompt and run these commands (bold text is typed manually)

```
ibug@ubuntu:~ $ adb shell
shell@android:/ $ su
root@android:/ # cd /data/system
root@android:/ # rm -f password.key gesture.key lock*
root@android:/ # reboot
```

and you'll see your Tab automatically reboots to the normal system, with lockscreen gone.

Answer (score 0):

If you logged in with your Google account, you should be able to see a 'forgot password' option after you have entered the wrong password 5 times. Your Google password will let you reset it.

Though only Medium-Low security passcodes can let you do that. If you do a High secuity passcode it will just enlongate the time to wait until you can try combinations again.